# Set function is a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Show that the set function $\mu$, defined on subsets $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ defined by 
$$ \mu(A) = \sum_{n \in A} 2^{-n}$$
is a measure.

The sum of the empty set is defined to be zero and 
$\mu (\cup A_i) = \sum \mu(A_i)$, for finite $A_i$.
Do I have to use 
$$\sum_{k \in A} 2^{-k} = \sup \{\sum_{k \in F}  2^{-k}, F \subset A, |F| <\infty \}$$ if $|A_i| = \infty$ or is there some easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a sequence $(A_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, $A_i \subset \mathbb{N}$, $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$. Then $$
  \mu\left(\bigcup A_i\right) = \sum_{n \in \bigcup A_i} 2^{-n} \doteq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n \in A_k} 2^{-n} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(A_k) \text{,}
$$
where $\doteq$ follows from the fact that all the summands are positive, and you may hence reorder the sum at will (plus of course the fact that all the $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint).

Comment: Thanks, from where does it follow that we can reorder the sum? Can you expand a little on that?

Comment: @Johan As I said, because all terms as positive. That's a standard result about infinit sums. One way to derive it is to no

Comment: It's a standard result about infinite sums. Very roughtly, the partial sums of an infinite sum with non-negative coefficients converges monotonically, which allows you to swap the limits in question freely enough to make this work. Note, BTW, that without that, it doesn't even make sense to write $\sum_{n\in A} 2^{-n}$ - that sum doesn't even *specify* a summation order!